# HttpListener Issue

Tags: jquery, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I'm writing a console application program as httplistener and using it through jquery and it's working completely true but I want to convert it to https  but i don't know the steps

Here is my code 
I hope any one can solve it quickly

This is the jquery code which is written in JScript.js file

```
 $(function () {
    //this code is executed when the page's onload event fires
    $("#runSample1").click(function () {
        var userNameJS = $("#uName").val();
        var passwordJS = $("#passw").val();
        $.post("http://localhost:80/", { userName: userNameJS, password: passwordJS }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });

    });
});
```

this is the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"> </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JScript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1 {
            width: 109px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>

    <tr>
        <td class="style1"><label >User Name</label></td>
        <td><input id="uName"  type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1"><label >Password</label></td>
        <td><input id="passw"  type="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1"><input id="runSample1"  type="button" value="Send" style="width: 62px"/>  </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and the httplistener code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
namespace TestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required to use the HttpListener class.");
                return;
            }
            // Create a listener.
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            //listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
            //listener.AuthenticationSchemes
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            for (; ; )
            {
                HttpListenerContext ctx = listener.GetContext();
                new Thread(new Worker(ctx).ProcessRequest).Start();
            }
        }
    }
    [DataContract]
    internal class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        internal string name;

        [DataMember]
        internal int age;
    }
    class Worker
    {
        private HttpListenerContext context;
        public Worker(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void ProcessRequest()
        {

            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            List<Person> eList = new List<Person>();
            Hashtable formVars = new Hashtable(); 
            Person person;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10;i++ )
            {
                person = new Person();
                person.name = "Pesron " + i;
                person.age = i;
                eList.Add(person);
            }
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding);
            // S contain parameters and values
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string[] pairs = s.Split('&');
            for (int x = 0; x < pairs.Length; x++)
            {
                string[] item = pairs[x].Split('=');
                formVars.Add(item[0],item[1]);
            }
            String userName = formVars["userName"].ToString();
            String password = formVars["password"].ToString();
            //To send any object as json to client
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonObject = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
            System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            jsonObject.WriteObject(ms, eList);
            byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();
            response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            //These headers to allow all browsers to get the response
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Origin", "*");
            //This line to write to the resonse
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE is not sandboxing localhost. FF and other browsers do. They see the call to localhost as a call to the web, and this is not allowed.

You could try to add

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Origin: *
```

to the headers of the HttpListener. A good paper on why this is needed can be founded [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/).

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your idea but i want to say that the httplistener class already gets the request in all browsers but the problem in send back the response string which internet explorer gets and other browsers don't

Comment: i'm using  ie developer tools and when watching (data) in             $.post("http://localhost:80/", { userName: userNameJS, password: passwordJS }, function (data) {
            alert(data); 
        });                                                                    it shows the data  but when using firebug in mozilla it shows an error

Comment: Ok. Can you edit your post and by that tell us the error. It is not well seen to do chat like chats here.

Comment: ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: See my updated post. I still believe that it has something to do with XSS and browsers treating localhost different.

Comment: @fighter  You are seeing CORS.  FF is not sending a POST it is sending the pre-flight OPTIONS request.  Those headers that mslot suggested are the response you should send to OPTIONS so that FF knows it is ok to then send the POST as a second request.